# Reconnect to kafka from Goroutine

Tags: go, apache-kafka, concurrency

I want to write a message to kafka using Golang. I have the following code.

```
package kafkaK

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"
    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/snappy"
    "time"
)

var writer *kafka.Writer

func Configure() (w *kafka.Writer, err error) {
    dialer := &kafka.Dialer{
        Timeout:  10 * time.Second,
        ClientID: "123",
    }

    config := kafka.WriterConfig{
        Brokers:          []string{"localhost:9092"},
        Topic:            "test",
        Balancer:         &kafka.LeastBytes{},
        Dialer:           dialer,
        WriteTimeout:     10 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:      10 * time.Second,
        CompressionCodec: snappy.NewCompressionCodec(),
    }
    w = kafka.NewWriter(config)
    writer = w
    return w, nil
}

func Push(parent context.Context, key, value []byte) (err error) {
    message := kafka.Message{
        Key:   key,
        Value: value,
        Time:  time.Now(),
    }
    return writer.WriteMessages(parent, message)
}
```

I write to kafka in separate Goroutines.

```
func sendMessage(message string) {
    err := kafkaK.Push(context.Background(), nil, []byte(message))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

The call looks like

```
go sendMessage("message #" + strconv.Itoa(i))
```

1. It happens that kafka is unavailable, and I would like to reconnect to it. How to do it correctly if different Goroutines use the same kafka object, and only they know that an error has occurred and can initiate reconnection. Perhaps there is some other approach?
2. Which library is better to use for working with kafka?

I think it's possible to use a channel or context, but I'm new to go, so I don't really understand how it can be implemented yet

Comment: It's not really a `go` problem or necessarily an issue with the library (some may provide connection management). `channel` and `context` in go aren't solutions, they're machinery/features `go` provides to wire together your programs. In your use-case you want to manage connection state. So perhaps you manage your connections in a structure and this structure could have a method that returns a connection IE:`GetConnection() *kafka.Writer` and in this method, before you return the connection, you check if it's valid and reconnect/raise-error etc.

Comment: @John Yes, this is not a problem with `go`. But, for example, in java, I know how to solve it, but I don't understand it yet. It seems to me there will be a problem if two goroutines call the `GetConnection()`, both will get an error and start reconnecting if they use the same `KafkaWriter`. And if I make  KafkaWriter for each goroutine, there will be too many of them

Answer (score 3):

First I want to point out that you're using a deprecated interface in kafka-go. [This](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/blob/main/writer.go#L31) documentation specifies that you can use kafkago.Writer{} to supply the config to connect and write to you kafka cluster. Now to answer your questions:

> It happens that kafka is unavailable, and I would like to reconnect to it. How to do it correctly if different Goroutines use the same kafka object, and only they know that an error has occurred and can initiate reconnection. Perhaps there is some other approach?

With a high level library like kafka-go, you don't have to worry about handling connections or transient errors like temporary unavailability of your kafka cluster. When you use the `WriteMessages` method on kafka writer, it buffers your messages and flushes periodically after connecting to your brokers using the config you provide to it. So, as long as the config is correct kafka-go will handle the rest for you.

> Which library is better to use for working with kafka?

kafka-go is definitely widely [used](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/stargazers) and actively maintained for reading and writing to kafka.

Also, back to your example, this is how I would refactor it:

```
package kafkak

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// Define an interface so you can mock it for testing.
type kproducer interface {
    WriteMessages(ctx context.Context, msgs ...kafka.Message) error
}

type KafkaK struct {
    p      kproducer
    dataCh chan kafka.Message // Write messages to this channel so a separate go routine can process them
    errCh  chan error // Fetch errors from this channel
    stopCh chan struct{}
}

func NewKafkaK(p kproducer) *KafkaK {
    k := &KafkaK{
        p:      p,
        dataCh: make(chan kafka.Message),
        errCh:  make(chan error),
        stopCh: make(chan struct{}),
    }

    go k.processLoop()

    return k
}

func (k *KafkaK) Push(key, value string) {
    m := kafka.Message{
        Key:   []byte(key),
        Value: []byte(value),
        Time:  time.Now(),
    }

    k.dataCh <- m
}

func (k *KafkaK) processLoop() {
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-k.dataCh:
            ctx, _ := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), time.Now().Add(time.Second*5))
            err := k.p.WriteMessages(ctx, msg)
            k.errCh <- err
        case <-k.stopCh:
            break
        }
    }
}

func (k *KafkaK) Stop() {
    close(k.stopCh)
    close(k.errCh)
}

func (k *KafkaK) Errs() <-chan error {
    return k.errCh
}
```